# How common is entanglement?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

In scientifically educated layperson terms (someone who remembers their college math and physics classes from a STEM related degree but never pursued physics specifically), how common is quantum entanglement and why? The basic question I am asking is whether entanglement is rare i.e. occurring seldom in natural environments, ordinary i.e. occurring frequently in natural environments, or ubiquitous i.e. occurring constantly in almost all matter. Good answers may also consider the following:

- Environmental factors such as temperature: how is entanglement related to these conditions and where would I find these conditions in nature? e.g. space vacuum vs. Earth vs. interior of star
- Duration of entanglement: how long particles** tend to stay in entangled states
- Number of particles typically involved in an entangled system: just two? a small counting number? a microscopic quantity of matter? a macroscopic quantity of matter? practically all matter?
- Locality of entanglement: on order of particle size? atomic scale? microscopic scale? macroscopic scale? unfathomably large scale?
- Trends over time: does the universe slowly trend toward or away from favoring highly entangled states?
- Degree of entanglement: do individual particle states tend to be almost completely independent, almost perfectly correlated, or somewhere in between? Does this distribution have a well defined shape?
- Kind of particle: do some kinds of particles tend to entangle differently or more or less frequently than others?
- Extraordinary natural environments: how do we think the answer changes for highly unusual or difficult to observe environments such as the interiors of black holes or neutron stars?
- Gaps in understanding: what aspects of my question are ill-formed, or alternately where does science not yet have a good answer to a well-formed question?

** I mean subatomic particles, but edify me if these concepts are relevant to larger particles too.